# Python not sending all data, only 4kb

Tags: python, sockets, web, server

I am attempting to create a Python web server however it seems to not be able to send any files larger then 4KB. If the file is above 4KB in size it just cuts off the end of the text/image past 4KB. Anything embedded from other sources (Amazon S3/Twitter) work fine.

Here is the server code. It is a bit of a mess at the moment but I am focused on getting it to work. Afterwards I will add more security to the code.

```
'''
    Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys
import time
import os
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 80 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        print data
        dataSplit = data.split(' ')
        print dataSplit

        contentType = "text/html"

        if(dataSplit[1].endswith(".html")):
            print "HTML FILE DETECTED"
            contentType = "text/html"
        elif(dataSplit[1].endswith(".png")):
            print "PNG FILE DETECTED"
            contentType = "image/png"
        elif(dataSplit[1].endswith(".css")):
            print "CSS FILE DETECTED"
            contentType = "text/css"
        else:
            print "NO MIMETYPE DEFINED"

        conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nServer: TestWebServ/0.0.1\nContent-Length: ' + str(os.path.getsize('index.html')) + '\nConnection: close\nContent-Type:' + contentType + '\n\n')

        print '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'

        with open(dataSplit[1][1:]) as f:
            fileText = f.read()
            n = 1000
            fileSplitToSend = [fileText[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(fileText), n)]
            for lineToSend in fileSplitToSend:
                conn.sendall(lineToSend)
            break

        if not data:
            break

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: May be Transfer-Encoding = "chunked" could help.

Comment: I tried changing the transfer encoding but now Chrome won't even display anything. It claims the webpage is not available with nothing in the console. For reference the new string is `conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nServer: TestWebServ/0.0.1\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\nConnection: close\nContent-Type:' + contentType + '\n\n')`

Comment: I checked and it attempts to send the content to Chrome but for some reason Chrome won't see the content. If I go back to using the Content-Length system it will send files but only the first 4KB. If I try to send the whole file at once it still only receives the first 4KB in Chrome.

Comment: i think problem is because of you hardcoded - os.path.getsize('index.html'), changing to dataSplit[1][1:] works with your original codes here.

Comment: Thank you. That has solved my problem. I can't believe I made that mistake and overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks you the user "YOU" we found the problem. I had this code:

```
conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nServer: TestWebServ/0.0.1\nContent-Length: ' + str(os.path.getsize('index.html')) + '\nConnection: close\nContent-Type:' + contentType + '\n\n')
```

instead of this code:

```
conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nServer: TestWebServ/0.0.1\nContent-Length: ' + str(os.path.getsize(dataSplit[1][1:])) + '\nConnection: close\nContent-Type:' + contentType + '\n\n')
```

The problem was that I was sending the file size for index.html for every file, so Chrome and other browsers just removed the extra data. It just so happened index.html was 4KB so I though it was a packet limitation or something in that area.